# Moved file to Music library in Windows 7, where did it go?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search, windows-libraries

I was in the folder for my user name, the one with subfolders of My Documents, My Pictures, My Videos, etc.  I was using a search to locate certain family videos to make a DVD.  I clicked on a file and dragged it over to Windows Live Movie Maker, but I accidentally let go while the mouse was over the Music Library (I think).  Now, I can't find it.  Since it was a search of many subfolders, I'm not 100% sure what the file was.  But, I did confirm that my search now yields one less video than it did before so I'm pretty sure it got moved somehow.  Any ideas?

I look in My Pictures, My Videos, etc.

Comment: Did you try ctrl+z to undo the move?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what file type it was?  If so you could try typing *. followed by the file extension into the search box, either in the directory search box or in the 'search files and programs' box (click start and type in the box there).
For example, typing

*.avi

in the search box will bring up all .avi files.  Other video file types are .wmv or .mp4

It's probably the same as your other video files.